# How does one gracefully end HTTP2 communications in Node

Tags: node.js, http2

How does one gracefully end HTTP2 communications between a client and server in Node?

To do so one has to end the following objects using the relevant methods and events:

```
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|       Object        | Relevant Methods |    Relevant Events    |
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Http2Server         | close            | close                 |
| ServerHttp2Session  | close            | close, goaway         |
| Http2ServerResponse | end              | finish, close         |
| ServerHttp2Stream   | end, close       | finish, end and close |
| ClientHttp2Session  | close            | close, goaway         |
| ClientHttp2Stream   | end, close       | finish, end and close |
+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

My thoughts are it could be something like:

```
clientHttp2Stream.end()     // close write side
clientHttp2Stream.close()   // required?
```

then

```
serverHttp2Stream.end() // or http2ServerResponse.end()?
serverHttp2Stream.close()
```

then

```
serverHttp2Stream.on('end',()=>http2Server.close())
```

and

```
clientHttp2Stream.on('end',()=>clientHttp2Session.close())
```

However, this raises the `abort` event for http2ServerRequest and serverHttp2Stream

If `.close()` is not called on the streams, then serverHttp2Session raise a `goaway` event which may be right?

Comment: Is your code acting a HTTP/2 server or client? The `ClientHttp2Session` and `ClientHttp2Stream` classes don't apply if you're only writing server-code.

Comment: @Dai it is inherited from streams

Comment: Yeah, I caught that just now and deleted my comment.

Comment: @Dai - both - I'm asking how the client and server should gracefully end their communications.